# Is it possible to integrate an C++ UI inside a Website?

Tags: c++, user-interface, web, embed, desktop

I need your help on something.

I got an C++ application divided in two sub programs working together.
The first program gets data from a device and fill, through a buffer, a second program that displays the data on a graphical window (an UI).

I need to **integrate this UI** on a website that can run locally on the same computer executing the C++ application.

Right now, I am launching my C++ application thanks to a **protocole handler**.
In my website, I am calling this protocol with `<a href="app:myparams" />`.
It launchs my application and I got the UI opening but it needs to be embed/inside the same website launching it.

What I tried:

- Recompile the application in **WebAssembly** and execute it inside a website.
  *Problem: Creating shared memory and fork (for my buffer) are currently not supported in WebAssembly.*
- Create a **virtual machine** with my application running inside. Then access it through a web interface manager for virtual machine (like vmware Horizon https://move.odu.edu/) by embedding it inside my website.
  *Problem: Bold solution (I know), refused by my superior.*
- Use an iframe for the UI.
  *Problem: There is no url I can provide for it.*

NB: I didn't developped this application and can't really redevelop it. The application is supposed to stay as it is.

I know that browsers are restricting that kind of things due to security issues. But I wanted to know if there are some solutions even temporary to make it work.

I hope I was clear enough. Thank for your time and your help.

Comment: Server-side scripting (e.g. PHP or CGI) to invoke the first program (that gathers the data) and then parse the data and display it in a HTML document?

Comment: I need to keep this application as it is, one program gathering the data and the other one displaying it through a graphical window. I didnt developped the application and I cant really redevelop it.

Comment: Can the UI program connect over the network to fetch the data? Then let the users download it and run (big security issues). Or some kind of remote desktop connection to a server where the UI program runs. That's about the only possible practical solution. Perhaps you need to talk to your project team about this assignment, ask for clarifications about the requirements and limitations, because it seems you have been given an impossible task otherwise.

Comment: I am stuck with one computer so it's not a solution. Basically, on my website I should have one button and by clicking it, it launches the application and the UI shows inside the website like a pop-up. I don't think it's possible but I wanted more opinions and advices.

Comment: Probably yes, you need something like https://webui.me